# Change String into name to access dataframe (R)

Tags: r, string, loops, quantmod

it's the R-Beginner again.

I have the following problem: I have a vector containing strings which is used to get some Dataframes through quantmod's `GetSymbols()`:

```
library(quantmod)
tickers = c("GOOG", "XOM", "GE", "KO", "F", "GS", "AIG", "HPQ", "WMT", "MSI")
n = length(tickers)



for (i in 1:n){
    getSymbols(Symbols = tickers[i], from=start, to=end, src="yahoo")
```

now my problem is the following: I want to access the specific dataframe within this loop and maybe extract the ".Close"-column of it in it's own vector. 
I tried the following (and several other tries):

```
   adress = tickers[i]
   price.[i]  = cbind(adress[,4])


}
```

But obviously it does not work because adress just is a string.
So my question is, how can i convert the string into another datatype that this "function" adresses the dataframe created before by GetSymbols in a manner that the loop still works; My next question is if the iteration on `price.[i]` does work so that i have n vectors for that with each a different name?

The sense behind all this is to abstract the scripts i created so far that it does neither matter how many Symbols i have and that i don't have to do the work for each of them when i use for example dygraph or rCharts or whatever, which then will be finish of the script giving charts on all of the ticker's closing prices.

I hope that my language was understandable. I also excuse myself that this might be a dumb question as i am still an R-Beginner trying to get into this for my new work;

Thank you guys for reading and helping me. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that a list is the way to go. However I would avoid using a loop. Try this instead:

```
tickers = c("GOOG", "XOM", "GE", "KO", "F", "GS", "AIG", "HPQ", "WMT", "MSI")
getSymbols(tickers, from = start, end = end)
```

If you want prices in a matrix:

```
prices = do.call(merge, lapply(tickers, function(x) Cl(get(x)))
names(prices) = tickers
```

Or if you want prices as a vector:

```
prices = lapply(tickers, function(x) get(x))
names(prices) = tickers
```

Comment: I appreciate all of your answers and am very thankful! This one fitted me best to use my results for dygraph then. Thank you very much, guys!

Answer (score 0):

First, note that `getSymbols` does not return a data.frame by default. It returns an xts object, which is a matrix with an time-based index.

The recommended way to solve your problem is to use `lapply` over the tickers to create a list.  Here's an example that creates a named list. Note that you need to set `auto.assign = FALSE` to make `getSymbols` return the data, instead of loading it.

```
library(quantmod)
tickers <- c("GOOG", "XOM", "GE", "KO", "F", "GS", "AIG", "HPQ", "WMT", "MSI")

# A named list
Data <- setNames(lapply(tickers, getSymbols, src = "yahoo", auto.assign = FALSE), tickers)
# Use lapply again to extract the close for each symbol
Close <- lapply(Data, Cl)
# Accessing a specific ticker's data
head(Close[[tickers[1]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using the `tidyquant` package. I believe this does exactly what you need: Gets the prices for each of the stocks in a data frame (or "tibble" for tidy data frame) using one succinct call to `tq_get()`, and then sets you up to perform analysis on groups withing the data frame using the `group_by()` function.

```r
library(tidyquant)

tickers <- c("GOOG", "XOM", "GE", "KO", "F", "GS", "AIG", "HPQ", "WMT", "MSI")
stock_prices <- tq_get(tickers, 
                       get  =  "stock.prices", 
                       from = "2016-01-01", 
                       to   = "2016-12-31")
stock_prices %>%
    group_by(symbol) 
#> Source: local data frame [2,520 x 8]
#> Groups: symbol [10]
#> 
#>    symbol       date   open    high     low  close  volume adjusted
#>     <chr>     <date>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1    GOOG 2016-01-04 743.00 744.060 731.258 741.84 3272800   741.84
#> 2    GOOG 2016-01-05 746.45 752.000 738.640 742.58 1950700   742.58
#> 3    GOOG 2016-01-06 730.00 747.180 728.920 743.62 1947000   743.62
#> 4    GOOG 2016-01-07 730.31 738.500 719.060 726.39 2963700   726.39
#> 5    GOOG 2016-01-08 731.45 733.230 713.000 714.47 2450900   714.47
#> 6    GOOG 2016-01-11 716.61 718.855 703.540 716.03 2090600   716.03
#> 7    GOOG 2016-01-12 721.68 728.750 717.317 726.07 2024500   726.07
#> 8    GOOG 2016-01-13 730.85 734.740 698.610 700.56 2501700   700.56
#> 9    GOOG 2016-01-14 705.38 721.925 689.100 714.72 2225800   714.72
#> 10   GOOG 2016-01-15 692.29 706.740 685.370 694.45 3592400   694.45
#> # ... with 2,510 more rows
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting out, I was confused about how to operate on an object (e.g., an xts object like SPY) instead of the string representing the object ("SPY"), and vice-versa.

Here are 2 functions that address this issue:

```
Str2Obj <- function(aString)   {eval(parse(text=aString))}

Obj2Str <- function(anObjName) {deparse(substitute(anObjName))}
```

For example, to extract data from assets downloaded with GetSymbols and return an xts object:

```
getAssetPrices <- function(assetNames, 
                  select = c("Ad","Cl","Op","Hi","Lo","Vo")) { #1
 worker <- function(assetName, select) { #2 
      asset <- Str2Obj(assetName)
      switch(select,
               "Ad" = Ad(asset),"Cl" = Cl(asset),
               "Op" = Op(asset),"Hi" = Hi(asset),
               "Lo" = Lo(asset),"Vo" = Vo(asset)
             )
      } #2
 lapply(assetNames, worker, select[1]) %>% do.call(merge.xts, .)
} #1

prices <- getAssetPrices(c("AAPL","ADBE","ADSK"), select = "Ad")

head(prices,3)

#               AAPL.Adjusted ADBE.Adjusted ADSK.Adjusted
# 1995-01-03        1.2239        3.5876        8.7046
# 1995-01-04        1.2558        3.4890        8.9666
# 1995-01-05        1.2398        3.6255        8.9666
```

Str2Obj and Obj2Str work for any name <=> object conversions.